# How to display HTML in TextView?

Tags: android, html, xml-parsing, textview

I have simple **HTML**:

```
<h2>Title</h2><br>
<p>description here</p>
```

I want to display HTML styled text it in `TextView`. How to do this?

Comment: Do you want to display the tags or omit them?

Comment: check out this link for working example http://javatechig.com/2013/04/07/how-to-display-html-in-android-view/

Comment: If you are looking for deprecated's solution, it just right here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904739/html-fromhtml-deprecated-in-android-n

Comment: textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("your HTML"));
is best method to show only HTML tags. also there is a method to play JS.

Comment: Android does not support all the HTML tags. Check this https://arkapp.medium.com/android-set-html-in-text-view-b912e1a96b21 to understand better how to use in text view.

Answer (score 1580, accepted):

You need to use [`Html.fromHtml()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) to use HTML in your XML Strings. Simply referencing a String with HTML in your layout XML will not work.

This is what you should do in Java

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
} else { 
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));
}
```

And in Kotlin:

```
textView.text = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
} else {
    Html.fromHtml(html)
}
```

Comment: when i put these lines gap occurs between h2 and p even i have removed br but still there is a gap...how to resolve it??

Comment: `h2` by definition creates a lot of margin around itself. and `p` also comes with some margin. if you don't want the gap, you might want to consider using other html elements.

Comment: how can I set html text within style attribute to textview control? It probably not work.

Comment: Can I put tags in XML strings?

Comment: Kostadin, you can put tags in XML, you just need to wrap them in CDATA brackets.

Comment: Can't we put <table><tr><td> like over here?

Comment: For those who want it to work with the ol/ul/li tags, check out this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3150456/1369016

Comment: That should be `android.text.Html.fromHtml`. I know most IDEs will fix it for you but for readability it is nicer to know the package names.

Comment: A list of tags supported by this method can be found [here](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html)

Comment: @Martin I wouldn't say *for readability* but rather *for exhaustivity*. IMO fully qualified names used directly in code like this are less readable than short names. But I agree with you on the fact that an answer like this should provide the package (on a side note), which the point of the link here ;)

Comment: This actually fixed a problem with rendering RSS feeds that contained HTML data.... If you get strange character encoding errors like the "diamond", it's probably caused by HTML within with RSS content which can be resolved with this solution +100

Comment: any idea, how to display div content value in textview, here is the my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512453/how-to-display-div-html-content-in-android-on-textview

Comment: This html doesn't display formatted: <p dir="ltr"><b>Suspected </b><b>jihadists</b><b> kill three at </b><b>U.N</b><b>. base in north Mali</b><br></p> <p dir="ltr">By&#160;Tiemoko Diallo</p> <p dir="ltr">BAMAKO&#160;(Reuters) - The United Nations said unknown attackers fired rockets at a U.N. peacekeeping base in Kidal in northern Mali on Saturday, killing three people inside, in the latest sign that the West African country's Islamist insurgency is intensifying.</p>

Comment: Why Html.fromHtml(htmlText) returns commented texts if it exists?

Comment: It doesn't do alignment either. So pretty much useless, like most Android apis.

Comment: @Guy: Nop. It doesn't work for <ul> and <li>. Not just them, there are few other tags as well which does not work with this. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3150456/1987045

Comment: This method was deprecated in API level 24

Comment: Deprecated function.

Comment: For Deprecated funcion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904739/html-fromhtml-deprecated-in-android-n

Comment: Small update: add annotation: @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N), for version compatibility

Comment: How can i do this if i get string from json by volley?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: Yeah this works fine but hyperlink showing in white color .

Answer (score 89):

**setText(Html.fromHtml(bodyData))** is **deprecated** after api 24. Now you have to do this:

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
      tvDocument.setText(Html.fromHtml(bodyData,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
 } else {
      tvDocument.setText(Html.fromHtml(bodyData));
 }
```

Comment: Why uses FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY in API 24+?

Comment: This help me a lot. But still not all tags are supported https://arkapp.medium.com/android-set-html-in-text-view-b912e1a96b21

Answer (score 74):

Have a look on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8558249/450148

It is pretty good too!!

```
<resource>
    <string name="your_string">This is an <u>underline</u> text demo for TextView.</string>
</resources>
```

It works only for few tags.

Comment: Is there any list of tags that are supported by this method?

Comment: @mente According to [source codes](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/text/Html.java): <a>, <b>, <big>, <blockquote>, <br>, <cite>, <dfn> <div align="...">, <em>, <font size="..." color="..." face="..."> <h1-6>, <i>, <img src="...">,  <p>, <small> <strike>,  <strong>, <sub>, <sup>, <tt>, <u> (source: http://www.dzone.com/snippets/how-display-html-android)

Comment: @JerabekJakub but take care, if you are going to handle img you have to implements Html.ImageGetter.

Comment: @0mahc0 when one implements img is it possible to set the size?

Comment: @Joh yes its possible. When you are implementing .ImageGetter, there is a method called getDrawable(String source). If u need more help, create a question and tag me, I will give you an example ;)

Answer (score 46):

If you want to be able to configure it through xml without any modification in java code you may find this idea helpful. Simply you call init from constructor and set the text as html

```
public class HTMLTextView extends TextView {
    ... constructors calling init...
    private void init(){
       setText(Html.fromHtml(getText().toString()));
    }    
}
```

xml:

```
<com.package.HTMLTextView
android:text="@string/about_item_1"/>
```

Comment: What's '...'. Please clarify

Comment: This is the more generic & clean solution

Comment: Simpler would be to just create a binding adapter, no?

@BindingAdapter(value = ["htmlText"])
fun TextView.setHtmlText(string: String?) {
    text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(string?:"", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
}

Answer (score 39):

If you are trying to show HTML from a string resource id, the formatting may not show up on screen.  If that is happening to you, try using CDATA tags instead:

```
strings.xml:
<string name="sample_string"><![CDATA[<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>]]></string>
```

...

```
MainActivity.java:
text.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.sample_string));
```

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13893926/923920) for further details.

Comment: Thanks, this did it for me- using API 23.

Answer (score 31):

I know this question is old. Other answers here suggesting [`Html.fromHtml()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html) method. I suggest you to use [`HtmlCompat.fromHtml()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/text/HtmlCompat) from `androidx.core.text.HtmlCompat` package. As this is backward compatible version of `Html` class.

Sample code:

```
import androidx.core.text.HtmlCompat;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.widget.TextView;

String htmlString = "<h1>Hello World!</h1>";

Spanned spanned = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(htmlString, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT);

TextView tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_id);

tvOutput.setText(spanned);
```

By this way you can avoid Android API version check and it's easy to use (single line solution).

Comment: How is that different than old methot? What is html mode purpose?

Comment: Was looking for something like this. Thanks :)

Comment: I specially logged in to upvote your answer. That what everyone should use. Thanks.

Comment: This is the best Answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 27):

The below code gave best result for me.

```
TextView myTextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
htmltext = <your html (markup) character>;
Spanned sp = Html.fromHtml(htmltext);
myTextview.setText(sp);
```

Answer (score 14):

```
String value = "<html> <a href=\"http://example.com/\">example.com</a> </html>";
    SiteLink= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSite);
    SiteLink.setText(Html.fromHtml(value));
    SiteLink.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: how do you change the color of the anchor?

Comment: android:textColorLink="color"

Comment: this will color the entire textview to red, but if I only want the anchor tags, I need to wrap the <a> tag with <font> tags and add color in there

Answer (score 13):

If you just want to display some html text and don't really need a `TextView`, then take a `WebView` and use it like following:

```
String htmlText = ...;
webview.loadData(htmlText , "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

This does not restrict you to a few html tags either.

Comment: While this is a very useful way to get around the restricted set of html tags, supported by TextView, it has the disadvantage that it **does not work well** with `layout_height="wrap_content"`. You will have to set an explicit height or match_parent instead.

Comment: webview is very slow

Answer (score 12):

The best approach to use CData sections for the string in strings.xml file to get a actual display of the html content to the TextView the below code snippet will give you the fair idea.

```
//in string.xml file
<string name="welcome_text"><![CDATA[<b>Welcome,</b> to the forthetyroprogrammers blog Logged in as:]]> %1$s.</string>

//and in Java code
String welcomStr=String.format(getString(R.string.welcome_text),username);
tvWelcomeUser.setText(Html.fromHtml(welcomStr));
```

CData section in string text keeps the html tag data intact even after formatting text using String.format method. So, Html.fromHtml(str) works fine and you’ll see the bold text in Welcome message.

**Output:**

> Welcome, to your favorite music app store. Logged in as: username

Comment: Thanks, this did it for me- using API 23.

Comment: thanks, u saved my day :)  Just a small addition : We need to add this check to above code:                                                                                   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                // for 24 api and more
                textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(welcomStr, Html.FROM_HTML_OPTION_USE_CSS_COLORS));
            } else {
                // or for older api
                textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(welcomStr));
            } . The value for 2nd parameter flag for API>=24, can be anything as per requirement.

Answer (score 10):

It's worth mentioning that the method [Html.fromHtml(String source)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)) is deprecated as of API level 24. If that's your target API, you should use [Html.fromHtml(String source, int flags)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20int)) instead.

Answer (score 10):

Created **Kotlin** extensions to convert **html** from **String** -

```
fun String?.toHtml(): Spanned? {
    if (this.isNullOrEmpty()) return null
    return HtmlCompat.fromHtml(this, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I would like also to suggest following project: https://github.com/NightWhistler/HtmlSpanner

Usage is almost the same as default android converter:

```
(new HtmlSpanner()).fromHtml()
```

Found it after I already started by own implementation of html to spannable converter, because standard Html.fromHtml does not provide enough flexibility over rendering control and even no possibility to use custom fonts from ttf

Comment: I am getting following error :

Error:(80, 13) Failed to resolve: com.osbcp.cssparser:cssparser:1.5

How do I resolve this ?

Answer (score 6):

It has been suggested through various answers to use the [Html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) framework class as suggested here, but unfortunately this class has different behavior in different versions of Android and various unaddressed bugs, as demonstrated in issues [214637](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=214637), [14778](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14778), [235128](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=235128) and [75953](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75953).

You may therefore want to use a compatibility library to standardize and backport the Html class across Android versions which includes more callbacks for elements and styling:

> [Github project HtmlCompat](https://github.com/Pixplicity/HtmlCompat)

While it is similar to the framework's Html class, some signature changes were required to allow more callbacks. Here's the sample from the GitHub page:

```
Spanned fromHtml = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(context, source, 0);
// You may want to provide an ImageGetter, TagHandler and SpanCallback:
//Spanned fromHtml = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(context, source, 0,
//        imageGetter, tagHandler, spanCallback);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setText(fromHtml);
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters The previously closed answer was a duplicate of an answer to [this question in relation to the deprecation of a framework method](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37904739/154306). I've expanded on the reason using a compatibility library would be a better approach. I don't think it's reasonable to flag either question as duplicates of each other as they are clearly different.

Answer (score 6):

**simply use**
[image]

```
checkBoxTextView.text =
        Html.fromHtml("<p><font color=#666666>I agree to</font><font color=#0173B7>  <b><u>Terms & Conditions</u></b></font><font color=#666666> and the <u></font><b><font color=#0173B7>Privacy Policy</font></u></b></font></p>")
```

Answer (score 5):

Simple use `Html.fromHtml("html string")`. This will work. If the string has tags like `<h1>` then spaces will come. But we cannot eliminate those spaces. If you still want to remove the spaces, then you can remove the tags in the string and then pass the string to the method `Html.fromHtml("html string");` . Also generally these strings come from server(dynamic) but not often, if it is the case better to pass the string as it is to the method than try to remove the tags from the string.

Answer (score 5):

If you use `androidx.`* classes in your project, you should use `HtmlCompat.fromHtml(text, flag)`.

Source of the method is:

```
@NonNull
    public static Spanned fromHtml(@NonNull String source, @FromHtmlFlags int flags) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
            return Html.fromHtml(source, flags);
        }
        //noinspection deprecation
        return Html.fromHtml(source);
    }
```

It is better to use `HtmlCompat.fromHtml` than `Html.fromHtml` as there is less code- only one line of code, and it's recommended way to use it.

Comment: what should be passed in flags?

Answer (score 4):

I have implemented this using web view. In my case i have to load image from URL along with the text in text view and this works for me.

```
WebView myWebView =new WebView(_context);
        String html = childText;
        String mime = "text/html";
        String encoding = "utf-8";
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, mime, encoding, null);
```

Comment: For proper display of UTF-8 you need to set the MIME type to "text/html; charset=UTF-8".

Answer (score 4):

```
String value = html value ....
mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(value),TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
```

Answer (score 4):

Make a global method like:

```
public static Spanned stripHtml(String html) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(html)) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    return Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT);
                } else {
                    return Html.fromHtml(html);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

You can also use it in your Activity/Fragment like:

```
text_view.setText(stripHtml(htmlText));
```

Answer (score 3):

People have suggested subclass for TextView, WebView and all sorts of solutions. I wonder why nobody mentioned a simple [binding adapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters).

```
@BindingAdapter(value = ["htmlText"])
fun TextView.setHtmlText(string: String?) {
    text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(string?:"", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
}
```

So your TextView xml will look like

```
<TextView
   ...
   htmlText="<p>Your <b>HTML</b> text</p>"
   ... />
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you write custom text view basic HTML set text feature will be get vanished form some of the devices.

So we need to do following addtional steps make is work

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

    public CustomTextView(..) {
        // other instructions
        setText(Html.fromHtml(getText().toString()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use:

```
String variable="StackOverflow";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Hello : </b>"+ variable));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class HtmlTextView extends AppCompatTextView {

public HtmlTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

private void init(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        setText(Html.fromHtml(getText().toString(), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
    } else {
        setText(Html.fromHtml(getText().toString()));
    }
 }
}
```

update of [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27462961/2497264)

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to get the solution:

```
textView.setText(fromHtml("<Your Html Text>"))
```

Utitilty Method

```
public static Spanned fromHtml(String text)
{
    Spanned result;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        result = Html.fromHtml(text, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
    } else {
        result = Html.fromHtml(text);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple Kotlin extension function like this:

```
fun TextView.setHtmlText(source: String) {
    this.text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(source, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
}
```

And usage:

```
textViewMessage.setHtmlText("Message: <b>Hello World</b>")
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a somewhat hacky but still genius solution! I got the idea from [this article](https://codeburst.io/rich-text-editor-for-ios-using-wkwebview-440d88d73bbf) and adapted it for Android. Basically you use a `WebView` and insert the HTML you want to show and edit in an editable div tag. This way when the user taps the `WebView` the keyboard appears and allows editing. They you just add some JavaScript to get back the edited HTML and voila!

Here is the code:

```
public class HtmlTextEditor extends WebView {

    class JsObject {
        // This field always keeps the latest edited text
        public String text;
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void textDidChange(String newText) {
            text = newText.replace("\n", "");
        }
    }

    private JsObject mJsObject;

    public HtmlTextEditor(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mJsObject = new JsObject();
        addJavascriptInterface(mJsObject, "injectedObject");
        setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                loadUrl(
                        "javascript:(function() { " +
                            "    var editor = document.getElementById(\"editor\");" +
                            "    editor.addEventListener(\"input\", function() {" +
                            "        injectedObject.textDidChange(editor.innerHTML);" +
                            "    }, false)" +
                            "})()");
            }
        });
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        if (text == null) { text = ""; }

        String editableHtmlTemplate = "<!DOCTYPE html>" + "<html>" + "<head>" + "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1.0\" />" + "</head>" + "<body>" + "<div id=\"editor\" contenteditable=\"true\">___REPLACE___</div>" + "</body>" + "</html>";
        String editableHtml = editableHtmlTemplate.replace("___REPLACE___", text);
        loadData(editableHtml, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
        // Init the text field in case it's read without editing the text before
        mJsObject.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return mJsObject.text;
    }
}
```

And [here](https://gist.github.com/BurningAXE/6527743bc632d36d2eb3a9bef72400c1) is the component as a Gist.

Note: I didn't need the height change callback from the original solution so that's missing here but you can easily add it if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can build valid HTML for Android `TextView` using the [`HtmlDsl`](https://github.com/jaredrummler/HtmlDsl) library on Github: https://github.com/jaredrummler/HtmlDsl.

The library provides syntactic sugar to make the code more understandable and less error-prone by only supporting elements and attributes that are rendered by Android.

**Example creating some HTML:**

```kotlin
textView.setHtml {
    h3("Android Versions:")
    ul {
        li {
            a(href = "https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/get") {
                +"Android 12 Beta"
            }
        }
        li("Android 11")
        li("Android 10")
        li("Pie")
        li("Oreo")
        li("Nougat")
        li("Marshmallow")
        li("Lollipop")
        // ...
    }

    small {
        sub {
            +"by "
            a {
                href = "https://github.com/jaredrummler"
                text = "Jared Rummler"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Supported HTML elements for Android `TextView`:

```html
<a href="...">
<b>
<big>
<blockquote>
<br>
<cite>
<dfn>
<div align="...">
<em>
<font color="..." face="...">
<h1>
<h2>
<h3>
<h4>
<h5>
<h6>
<i>
<img src="...">
<p>
<small>
<strike>
<strong>
<sub>
<sup>
<tt>
<u>
<ul>
<li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using BindingAdapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("renderHtml")
fun bindRenderHtml(view: TextView, description: String?) {
if (description != null) {
    view.text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(description, FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
    view.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
} else {
    view.text = ""
}
```

}

usage:

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content_text_view"
        app:renderHtml="@{show.description}"
        ...
```