# how to get a value as htmltext on textview in android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display HTML in TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview)

I have a string that contains some tags(`<p>`,`<img>`,etc).

Tell how to handle these tags in textview.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check out for a working example http://javatechig.com/2013/04/07/how-to-display-html-in-android-view/

Answer (score 5):

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p>" + title + "</p>");
```

you can also user web view

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
 setContentView(webview);

 // Simplest usage: note that an exception will NOT be thrown
 // if there is an error loading this page (see below).
 webview.loadUrl("http://slashdot.org/");

 // Of course you can also load from any string:
 String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192 points.</body></html>";
 webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: hey i am asking about TextViews.....

Comment: Html.fromHtml() is not working properly. the tags are still shows as it is