# Android textview wrap around textview

Tags: android, textview

Is it possible to wrap a textview around a textview, where the 2nd textview would wrap to the next line under the first textview?

For example:

```
<This is one textview> <This is 
another textview>
```

I have tried using `android:layout_weight="1"` and relative layouts, however, they dont produce this effect.

Comment: No, and why would you do that?

Comment: customer wants this effect, and I figured I need 2 textview because they need to be 2 different colors

Comment: This will be helpful to you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. If you're looking to format the two bits of text differently, consider [using spans](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#selectingtext) within one TextView.

Answer (score 0):

This will be helpful to you. You can get same effect with HTML in text view

[How to display HTML in TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview)

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible because the "another textview" would have a non-rectangular widget area then.