# Formatting TextView text using values/strings.xml, HTML and CSS

Tags: java, android, html, css

I am trying to format a TextView with lots of text to look better, and since I feel this is very easy with HTML and CSS I thought I'd give it a go. And since having it in values/strings.xml lets you localize, I found this to be the best option. Now, I manage to get HTML in a string fine with:

```
<![CDATA[ <html code here> ]]>
```

But if I try for example:

```
<![CDATA[
    <html>
    <head>
    <body>
    <style type=\"text/css\">
        p {
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #31B6E7; }
    </style>
    </head>
    ...
    etc
]]>
```

It will just paste the CSS code as plain text, is it not possible to format using CSS this way or does anyone have a good tip for me here?

Thanks for any help on this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to tell the TextView that it is receiving HTML. I think you can find you answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview). That goes for HTML. [CSS is not supported](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) - you have to do it via your layout XML...

Comment: CSS is not supported, bah, that sucks, thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 6):

I think you're perhaps expecting a little much from the TextView, or rather, from the Html.fromHtml method, since that is what turns the HTML into a Spannable that you can use with the TextView. It's quite basic. Here's what it supports:

http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html

Comment: Thanks for more clarification and the link.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [android.webkit.WebView.loadData()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) to render the HTML + CSS, instead of a TextView.