# MathJax with TextView in Android

Tags: android, textview, mathjax

I have some data which was formatted using `MathJax` on `WebApplication`. Now, I want to display those Data in Android App and that is in `TextView` only.
I have already downloaded `MathJax` from [Leathrum's WordPress](http://cs.jsu.edu/wordpress/?p=498)

I found some examples but all are using `WebView`. But I want it using `TextView`. How to get this ???
I am also using `ImageGetter` with that `TextView` and it is working fine. Now, just want to do something for `MathJax`.
**Why only `TextView` ???**
My data contains simple text, html text, images, and math functions... I was using webview but it is showing extra space at bottom and also have using with Webview because I am using Custom ListView with WebView

Comment: Please clarify the steps that you have taken?

Comment: @hoomi, I don't know how to set script and its path with `TextView`.

Comment: From a quick search on SO it looks like TextView is not designed for this kind of thing. As per [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718519/formatting-textview-text-using-values-strings-xml-html-and-css). JavaScript also does not seem supported.

Answer (score 3):

> But I want it using TextView. How to get this ?

You don't. `TextView` is not designed for this. Your choices are:

- Stick with `WebView`
- Figure out how to render your mathematical expressions to images, then either use an `ImageView`, `ImageSpan`, etc.
- Write your own widget that draws the mathematical expression to a `Canvas`

Answer (score 2):

*MathJax is a cross-browser JavaScript library that displays mathematical notation in web browsers, using MathML, LaTeX and ASCIIMathML markup.*

**Source:** [MathJax in Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax)

The very first line has an answer for you. It's a cross-browser javascript library. you can not use it for textviews. Doesn't it make sense ?

Update:

**Solution 1:** You could write a mapper which will have mapping of each Math symbols to its html code and use it to showcase on your TextView based on need.

**Solution 2:** There is a nice open source: [MathView](https://github.com/jianzhongli/MathView) Which is using MathJax internally that you can use.

Comment: Did you try text view.set text( HTML.fromHtml(your server response)); ? But I am not sure if it'll work.

Comment: Nope, My data contains some complicated html tags so `HTML.fromHtml` does not support it. `Spanned` with `ImageGetter` solved my that issue. Now, just `MathJax` is remaining.

Comment: Did you happen to find the solution. Even I have similar problem as you ,I want to render math expression on Textview. Can you tell me if you have achieved anything in that terms.

Comment: @veena No It won't work with TextView, However you can use WebViews to make use of MathJax.

Comment: Thanks is there any other possibility to do something like that?