# Add a simple link to a website on a activity

Tags: android

I´m looking for a easy tutorial to add a link to an activity. For example "password forgotten", after click on the link, the webbrowser should open the specified url.
Thank you very much
Regards, Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html

You could also use the HTML to Text functions:

[How to display HTML in TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview)

Answer (score 1):

Change the URL to whatever you want.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.mywebsite.com/"));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Is that a link to your app? Anyway please take a few seconds to remove the unnecessary indentation.

Comment: Sorry, was just copypasta

Comment: @Sam You are too supportive...

Comment: @Pragnani Yes I am, but I like to give everyone a chance. eskimoapps.com, that's much better.