# make parts of a string resource to hyperlink

Tags: android

I have a `String` resource containing my disclaimer Text. I use it in a `Dialog`:

```
    private void showDisclaimer() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Disclaimer")
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
            .setMessage(getString(R.string.disclaimer)).setCancelable(true)
            .setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();


                }
            });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

}
```

I want to make certain parts clickable and use them as http links. I tried the following but HTML markup seems to have no effect:

```
  <string name="disclaimer"> ...some things are trademarks of <a href="http://google.com/">Google</a> ................. </string>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview

Comment: the linked question does not discuss hyperlinks

Comment: Instead of a dialog, use a webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
<string name="disclaimer"><![CDATA[some things are trademarks of <a href="http://google.com/">Google</a>]]> </string>
```

and call

```
getResources().getText(R.string.disclaimer);
```

**or**

```
Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.disclaimer));
```

Comment: Now the text is highlighted and underlined as a link, though clicking on it has no effect. Any way to get it working?

Comment: Try adding this: .setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());