# Android - Bold Tags Arent Appearing In String Using Android Documentation Formating

Tags: java, android, string, textview

I'm attempting to make some text bold using the method shown in the android documentation but for some reason the text still isn't appearing bold.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling

XML:

```
<string name="updated_text">This is sample text. If this doesn\’t work, go to<b> news.google.com</b>; to find more infomation.</string>
```

JAVA:

```
TextView assistInstrText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.updated_text);
            assistInstrText.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.updated_text)));
            assistInstrText.setText(styledText);
```

Answer (score 0):

are u setting the text in a textview? because then when you set your text you might need to use [Html.fromHtml(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29)

see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview)

Comment: I'm using: 

 TextView assistInstrText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.updated_text);
    assistInstrText.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.updated_text)));
    assistInstrText.setText(styledText);

Comment: why setText called twice in a row? it seems you're overwriting the 1st setText call with the proper fromHtml call

Comment: Should I remove assistInstrText.setText(styledText);?

Comment: I need to keep the fromHtml call

Comment: yea, you don't show where you have instantiated that so im not sure exactly what your putting there, and the line assistInstrText.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.upda‌​ted_text))); is all you need to have your xml html text work

Comment: Are you sure? That results in assistInstrText cannot be resolved

Comment: if you have a layout xml file with a textview with an id of updated_text, then the line `TextView assistInstrText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.updated_text);` should work fine and resolve

Comment: I do - but now I'm getting 2 error stating assistInstrText cannot be resolved when using:    //TextView assistInstrText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.updated_text);
    assistInstrText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.updated_text);
    assistInstrText.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.updated_text)));
    //assistInstrText.setText(styledText);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39769/discussion-between-trippedout-and-hellomojo)