# How to set 3 Textview same line like this

Tags: android, xml

I want to set three `textview` contain in same row. I use `LinearLayout` . Unable to set properly.

Here is my XML :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/or"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:singleLine="true"
     /> 

        <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textColor="#54d66a"
    android:text="@string/login"
    android:textSize="25sp"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
     /> 

        <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"

    android:text="@string/email_details"
    android:textSize="25sp"

     /> 


  </LinearLayout>
```

May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?Maybe this question too basic, but i did't find any suitable solution.Please Help me out.

Comment: give  android:layout_weight="1" to each textView

Comment: @Manishika weight won't for this.

Comment: @blackbelt it will assign equal space based on parent layout but in user want to show text in equal line.

Answer (score 2):

you just need to remove `android:ems="10"` from TextView it will automatically in single line. check this code.

```
 <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/or"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#54d66a"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/email_details"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: @Amiya you should not ask for upvote like this. this is oppose to StackOverflow rules. and if answer is helpful to you and you got the solution you should accept the useful answer

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for 3 TextView's. You could combine the whole line into a single TextView. There are two possible solutions.
1. You can use [`SpannableString`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) to achieve the same effect. See this [post](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/177) for more information on Spannables. 
2. You can decorate that String using Html tags. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to achieve a different text color you can use HTML tags, for example:

```
String html = "or <font color="green">login </font> with your email address";
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(html), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add in horizontal linear-layout if you want add just one line.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/tabs_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
 <TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:text="@string/or"
android:textSize="25sp"
android:singleLine="true"
 /> 

 <TextView
android:id="@+id/textView3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ems="10"
android:textColor="#54d66a"
android:text="@string/login"
android:textSize="25sp"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
 /> 

    <TextView
android:id="@+id/textView4"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ems="10"
android:text="@string/email_details"
android:textSize="25sp"

 /> 
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution you don't mention the ems value in your layout i modified your layout use this one...

```
     <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" >

        <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="or"
    android1:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:singleLine="true"
     /> 

        <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#54d66a"
    android:text="login"
    android1:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
     /> 

        <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:text="with your e-mail address"
    android:textSize="25sp"

     /> 


  </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
tvWeblink = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1));
tvWeblink.setClickable(true);
tvWeblink.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
String text = "or <a href=\"<your_login_url>\"> login </a> with your e-mail address.";
tvWeblink.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Spannable` String:-

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview01);
Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("or Login with your e-mail address");        
wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 3, 8, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); //3- start of character 8- end of character to apply forground color
textView.setText(wordtoSpan);
```

---

Using `HTML` String:-

For better language compatibility support add your string inside `res/values/strings`

values/strings

```
<string name="Message">or<![CDATA[<font color='green'> Login</font>]]> with email address</string>
```

Snippet:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.strings.Message)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Check this one
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="or"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="login"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#54d66a"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="detail"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```