# HTML in TextView

Tags: android, html

The response of a web service is the following :

```
<span style="color:#DDFFEE;">You have to pay you bil before <b>12 june 2012</b> for your informations.</span></br></br> You have already a large time.
```

I want to display this in a TextView.

I can't just simply put the response below in a String and applicate

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(response));
```

It doesn't work because it can't be a String.

How can I do this dynamically please ?

[image]

Comment: Why can't it be a `String`?

Comment: have you got any issues?

Comment: The response from the web service can't be a String ! This is my issue

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put the String you get as a response, inside the `fromHtml` call, if it's not a String, maybe you just need to append `.toString()` to it, to get a String..

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>This is HTML</h2>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Html.fromHtml() to use HTML in your XML Strings. Simply referencing a String with HTML in your layout XML will not work.

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));
```

here : [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview)

Comment: You don't understand the question, my issue is that the response from web service can't be a String. I got errors.

Comment: response is an object ?? what type it has ?? you can convert it to a string .toString()