# WebView height as content height?

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I have a WebView in a vertical linear layout, after i load the web content (exactly an email) i want that the WebView size will fit the email so that i can't use zoom. Because the linear layout is in a ScrollView so i don't want the "double" scroll effect (WebView scoll in a scrollview).

What i want is simply the email content that will fit in the linear layout that i can scroll down.

I got the email content from a post request and added it to the WebView like this:

```
String content = jsonResult.getString("html_body");

mWvResponseOf.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, content, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Any help?

Comment: How is your `WebView` height is defined? Are you using `match_parent`? Please post your layout code.

Comment: as i understood you dont want to scroll webview horizontally am i right?

Comment: I didn't know that using "wrap_content" will resize the webview based on it's content. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use `TextView` inside your `LinearLayout`. Then use `Html.fromHtml()` method to get your work done.

For more clarification refer : [How to display HTML in TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview)