# How to Display HTML Text in Android TextView?

Tags: android, textview, tag-handler

I Have an HTML Text.

#### Sales Resources

- Drive to Collab Partner Presentation

  - US-Canada
  - [LATAM](https://google.com)
  - EMEAR
  - [APJC](https://google.com)
- Drive to Collab Program FAQs
- Platform for Voice and Video Campaign

I would like to display this text in Android Text View. I have tried MyTagHandler to display, it is working fine while displaying, but the text formating is not good. If the bulleted text has 2 lines then the second line is coming from first, but i need space upto bullet. how can i handle this?
[image: Problem Image]

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2116191/4384828

Answer (score 1):

i guess like this...

```
TextView foo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.foo);
foo.setText(Html.fromHtml("your html text"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in 2 ways.

1. First you create a HTML Script for it.

Once you are done with it, then set that to textview as shown below.
(preferable for smaller text)

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Html Script"));
```

2. Create a html file and put it in res/raw.

Then use the follwoing code.

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getHtmlText()));
```

Now define getHtmlText() method as below:

```
private String getHtmlText(){
 InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.my_html_file);
 ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 int i;
 try {
 i = inputStream.read();
  while (i != -1)
  {
   byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
   i = inputStream.read();
  }
  inputStream.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
  return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
}
```