# how to set HTML Tag in Textview in android?

Tags: html, textview

I am using Html Tag in TextView. But can not Proper display.
Please guide me.

example,
Payemt Bill: 
You can pay your bill:
• By mail: sending a check with your 
  invoice  abc abc abc on it. 
  Don’t forget to include your Phone no.
• In person: with any of our  receptionists.
• Online: fill out this form below.

If you have questions about your invoice, please call our billing department at 1000-1000-100

My code is,

```
txtPayBillOne.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        String strPayBillOne1="<p>You can pay your bill:<ul><li><b>By mail:</b> sending a check with your invoice abc abc abc  on it. Don’t forget to include your Phone no. </li><li><b>In person:</b> with any of our front desk receptionists. </li><li><b>Online:</b> fill out this <a href=\"https://payments.cboss.com/clients/pymt/maryscenterclinic/paymentlaunch/default.aspx\">form.</a></li></ul><br />If you have questions about your invoice, please call our billing department at 1000-1000-1000</p>";
        txtPayBillOne.setText(Html.fromHtml(strPayBillOne1);
```

How to use for this format? and how to get this format in TextView?

Comment: @zohar please see my updated Questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display HTML in TextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview)

Comment: How to set Paragraph type Text means leave some Space then after Text is started

Answer (score 0):

like this you can add Html to your text view

```
     String input = "<b>bold</b>";
     myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(input));
```

On the place of input you can provide your values.Hope this will help you

Comment: How to set Paragraph type Text means leave some Space then after Text is started