# "How to display div html content in android on textview

Tags: android, html, textview

I have value on string:

```
String htmlValue = "<div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: impact, chicago; font-size: 18px;">Exchange Offer !!&nbsp;</span></div>
    <div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 14px;">any mobile phone</span> , <span style="font-size: 14px;">give your</span> <span style="font-family: impact, chicago; font-size: 20px;">take new one</span>.</div>";
```

and how to display such type div included in textview.

I have try this but only content display div styling could not display.

```
Spanned result= Html.fromHtml(htmlValue);
tvFooter.setText(result);
```

or

```
 tvFooter.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlValue));
```

Here Defined:  http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html   , div supported but could get exact expected output by doing above.
I have both of above trick, but not working.

**Error Output:**

[image]

**Expected Output like this**

:[image]

Comment: htmlValue you have used must be string,check that if it is string,like "<div>..."

Comment: show code of where you set htmlValue

Comment: I got this string value from server, and just want to display on **textview**. what i try , i gave above sample.

Comment: but inside you have nested "", try putting \  before all " inside string

Comment: The " problem would cause a compile error. So that is unlikely to be the actual issue. @Bixms: The image, is that the expected output or the actual output. If it is not the actual output, please add an image of the actual output.

Comment: I don't immediately see why you are facing issues. However, there are different methods you can use as reported here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29004794/503508

Comment: @Knossos it does not even compile with multiple "

Comment: @Bixms it appears to be "style" tag is not supported : http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com.tr/2011/04/html-in-textviews.html

Comment: Are you sure that you have to use TextView? You can play with WebView.

Answer (score 2):

As I scanned the source code of *[/frameworks/base/core/java/android/text/Html.java](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/text/Html.java)* , the attribute `style` and the tag `span` are not supported. Suggest using webview instead of textview

Following tags or attributes seems to be supported in Lollipop,

```
 - <br>
 - <p>
 - <div>
 - <strong>
 - <b>
 - <em>
 - <cite>
 - <dfn>
 - <i>
 - <big>
 - <small>
 - <font color="..." face="...">
 - <blockquote>
 - <tt>
 - <monospace>
 - <a href="...">
 - <u>
 - <sup>
 - <sub>
 - <h1>
 - <h2>
 - <h3>
 - <h4>
 - <h5>
 - <h6>
 - <img src="...">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write \ before inside " because they're closing your string before they properly end, like Jemshit Iskenderov says.

Also, the tags style and span can't be shown in a textview. Check [this link](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) for a list of HTML tags that work in textview.

Answer (score 0):

All html tags are not supported by Html.fromHtml() [check here](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.in/2011/04/html-in-textviews.html) the supported tags in textview.So better you use webview instead of textview to load the html content. like

```
 yourwebview.loadData(yourhtmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```