# In which format (HTML/markdown/JSON) should I receive some formatted text from my server?

Tags: android, json, httpresponse

I am receiving JSON responses from my sever. Generally it is structuted data. But I am stuck in a particular case where, the data can be of any number of items, each item will have a heading text and some more lines.

a markdown example to show my use-case:

```
**Heading**
- indented normal text:
* bullet item
* bullet item 2
```

In which format (HTML/markdown/JSON) should I receive some formatted text from my server?
**Markdown** would be easy for me to create on the server while I dont know how I will parse it in android.
**JSON** would be hard to create on the server but easy to de-serialize in android.

I want to dynamically add this to a ListView, so I want each item to be inflatable to a list_view_item.xml . The entire thing is part of a larger XML. I want it as follows.

[image: list item to be populated]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON for objects, JSONArray for several JSONObjects.

It's not a difficult task to serialize in server! You can use libraries like [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) etc.

Best option for me.

Comment: I meant markdown is really easy. I have an admin panel, so I can enter text easily.

Comment: Then... The use of JSON really makes sense for me!!

Answer (score 0):

Android's `TextView` naturally supports several [html tags for formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview) so in case you don't use custom fonts and advanced formatting, html is the best choice.

As for parsing unknown amount of items, you can't get any better than sending a JSON array.

Comment: Formatting is not what I want. I would probably end up creating a "parser" that converts the JSON into TextViews