# Create a working link in TextView, which points to the html file from assets

Tags: android

I have a TextView with HTML text which contains two hyperlinks:

```
<string name="agreement"><![CDATA[By signing up I agree to <a href="file:///android_asset/terms.html">Terms of Use</a>, Payment terms and <a href="http://www.google.com">Legal Policy</a>]]></string>
```

Both links are clickable, but the first one fails to be opened by any viewer on my Nexus 5. Some application appears for a second, then it shuts down and a toast is saying "Cannot display PDF (terms.html cannot be opened)"

How can I make the local hyperlink open HTML file in browser?

Comment: Where is your terms.html placed in the project? Directly in the src\main\assets folder?

Comment: Right, directly in src\main\assets

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can simply use [webview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Comment: sure I can, but then I have to handle link clicks myself and split the TextView into clickable and not clickable ones.

Comment: okay here is one another solution that might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview