# ImageButton OnClick to show html content not working in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imagebutton

I need help to correct my codes.

I am trying to write code what direct `ImageButton` click to view html content.

Can any one help. `ImageButton` is not showing content, only  thing load is layout

Comment: share your code how fare you try..

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Where you want to show html content?

Answer (score 1):

If you want an ImageButton with a link to a web page then try this:

On the view, configure android:OnClick with the name of the function you will call

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/myImageButton"            
        android:onClick="viewHTMLContent"
/>
```

Then go to your class and configure the Onclick function like this:

```
        public class MyClass extends Activity{
        ImageButton myImageButton; 

            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
                myImageButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.myImageButton);        
        }

        public void viewHTMLContent(View v) {
           Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
           startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    }
```

if you want use your own html into a TextView(example), then you need to modify the viewHTMLContent() function:

```
public void viewHTMLContent(View v) {
     myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description</p>"));
}
```

follow this thread for more info [How to display HTML in TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview)

Comment: Hi bro....... you don't need to implements OnClickListener  and myImageButton.setOnClickListener(this); when you declare android:onClick="viewHTMLContent"