# TextView make part of text not bold

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, textview

I have a TextView title. I need it showing half of text bold and other half not bold. The way I set it is shown below:

category.getName() -- > Bold
"urinary tract infection" ---->not bold

```
 title.setText(category.getName()+ "\n(urinary tract infection)");
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: By using HTML, check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview)

Comment: did this : title.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>"+serviceName+"</b>")+"\n(urinary tract infection)"); did not work

Comment: title.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>"+serviceName+"</b>\n(ur‌​inary tract infection)"));  -- if the /n is for a new line you can do -- title.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>"+serviceName+"</b><br>(ur‌​inary tract infection)"));

Comment: Thanks everyone got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try formatting you TextView using HTML.

```
title.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>"+category.getName()+ "</b>\n(urinary tract infection)"));
```