# Justify Text in an Android App (Image has been added below )

Tags: java, android, xml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxhCb.png)I have an Android Application .  i have a page called Terms and Conditions.. the page is called from the web service . the text are not justified . how to justify the text ?

Comment: are you showing the text contained in html in a webview ?

Comment: i am showing the text contained in a text view which is called from a web service

Comment: the text is in html

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't support text justification. The only thing you can do is apply android:gravity="center"

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using XML layout.

```
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="YOURTEXT"
/>
```

add  `android:gravity="center"` **OR** add  `yourTextview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);` in JAVA

If you have text with HTML tags then you can use this like,

```
yourTextview.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));
```

Comment: my android:text= " "  is blank and the text is called from a service

Comment: web service * .....

Comment: if you want really hurt yourself, you can try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview I think you should probably set <p> to block mode with css

Comment: if yu get textview from webservice no problem...  remove  android:text="YOURTEXT" from xml and add yourTextview.setText(YourTextFromService);

Comment: also check updated answer for HTML text input

Comment: check  out the image i have posted in the question .. i want that page justified touching both sides of the screen

Comment: provide web service response

Comment: if you are using "Html.fromHtml" this code in Java then remove android:gravity="center"

Comment: i removed ..now the left side is justified but right hand site its uneven

Comment: provide HTML.. ..

Comment: public void doPostExecuteForCommu(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(jsonObject!=null){
            //{"status":1}
            try {

Comment: String desc=jsonObject.getString("termcond");
                termsofservice.setText(Html.fromHtml(desc));
} catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }