# Extract typeset symbols from html page to display in TextView

Tags: android, html, webview, textview, mathjax

I can use [MathJax](http://mathjax.org) to render Mathematical formula in `WebView` (so loaded content in WebView is completely under my control). Also we know we can [display HTML in TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2116162/1043882). Is there a way to extract typeset symbols from html page to display in `TextView`? Really I want to display the same thing that is displayed in `WebView` in `TextView`.

Comment: you mean font awesome icon in text view right?

Comment: @BhupatBheda I want to display the same thing that is displayed in WebView.

Comment: TextView is very limited when it comes to importing HTML. For example, I doubt it supports webfonts (which MathJax's HTML outputs need). You might have better luck with MathJax's SVG output.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger I need to display rendered formula along other text descriptions. Also combining `SVG` output with `automatic line break` causes error in `Android`.

Comment: TextView support minimum set of HTML tags.not support all HTML tags