# How to set this html String to textview with textcolor in android?

Tags: android, html

```
String data="<span style=\"color:#a52a2a;\">युद्ध प्रारंभ होने से पूर्व&nbsp;युधिष्ठिर&nbsp;रथ </span>से उतरकर पैदल ही पितामह भीष्म के पास गए तथा उनके चरणस्पर्श करके उन्हें प्रणाम किया। इसी प्रकार युधिष्ठिर ने&nbsp;कृपाचार्य&nbsp;और&nbsp;द्रोणाचार्य&nbsp;को भी प्रणाम किया तथा विजय का आशीर्वाद प्राप्त किया। युधिष्ठिर की धर्म-नीति को देखकर धृतराष्ट्र का पुत्र&nbsp;युयुत्सु&nbsp;इतना प्रभावित हुआ कि कौरन-सेना छोड़कर पांडवों से जा मिला।\n" +
                "<h2>\n" +
                "\tपहले दिन का युद्ध</h2>\n";
```

need this text in textview with color..
I just want to set this html to textview with his attribte and color and size

Answer (score 2):

To set HTML in the TextView:

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<span style=\"color:#a52a2a;\">युद्ध प्रारंभ होने से पूर्व&nbsp;युधिष्ठिर&nbsp;रथ </span>से उतरकर पैदल ही पितामह भीष्म के पास गए तथा उनके चरणस्पर्श करके उन्हें प्रणाम किया। इसी प्रकार युधिष्ठिर ने&nbsp;कृपाचार्य&nbsp;और&nbsp;द्रोणाचार्य&nbsp;को भी प्रणाम किया तथा विजय का आशीर्वाद प्राप्त किया। युधिष्ठिर की धर्म-नीति को देखकर धृतराष्ट्र का पुत्र&nbsp;युयुत्सु&nbsp;इतना प्रभावित हुआ कि कौरन-सेना छोड़कर पांडवों से जा मिला।\n" +
            "<h2>\n" +
            "\tपहले दिन का युद्ध</h2>\n", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
```

To change the color of the TextView:

```
holder.text.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

[How to display HTML in TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview) that would help you in setting the HTML to textview . And in the xml part of the textview simply type textcolor and it'll suggest you to add Android:textColor where you specify the appropriate color for you text