# How to convert HTML text into a String and set it into a TextView in android?

Tags: android, string, textview

I know that there are several similar topics already created, but I still haven't found an answer. I receive an HTML in JSON and need to clean it up from tags and set this clean String as a TextView. Unfortunately, standard Android method Html.fromHtml() doesn't work properly, it doesn't remove all tags. For example:

1) HTML text:  <div>At the exhibition everyone can watch a documentary about the life of boxers and see the modern multimedia show which translates on the interactive screens.</div>\r\n \r\n<div>Visitors will be able то live through with Klitschko brothers many moments of their lives.

2) After converting it into a String
`placeDescription = Html.fromHtml(obj.getString("detail_text")).toString();`
 the text is the same with tags.
What am I doing wrong? Are there any tools/libraries that can help me?

Comment: What is the declaration for `placeDescription`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice  public static String placeDescription;

Comment: I have a quasi unrelated to your problem: why is the variable static? I think you can declare it as a local variable in the method where you use it.

Comment: @ Code-Apprentice I use it several times. This will not help

Comment: This is an incorrect use of static. You are right that it will not fix your problem. You should still learn how to use static correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display HTML in TextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Look, my question is clear and you left tons of comments. None of your comments were useful. And my question is not a duplicate as those answers didn't fit. Do you have any idea of how to substitute method Html.fromHtml()?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain how what you want to do is different from the linked question. Using the example HTML in your question, what do you want to show in the TextView? Give a specific example.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice This String should be an answer: At the exhibition everyone can watch a documentary about the life of boxers and see the modern multimedia show which translates on the interactive screens. Visitors will be able то live through with Klitschko brothers many moments of their lives.

Comment: Please edit your question

Comment: The answers to the linked question as well as mine here will do exactly what you want.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The question is clear. Still none of your answers removed <div> tags

Comment: please reply to my last comment below my answer

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to display the HTML content without all the tags like in a browser. To do this, change

```
placeDescription = Html.fromHtml(obj.getString("detail_text")).toString();
```

to

```
CharSequence placeDescription = Html.fromHtml(obj.getString("detail_text"));
```

Then you need to call

```
myTextView.setText(placeDescription);
```

Comment: of course I know how to set TextView. The problem is that the method Html.fromHtml() doesn't clean Html text.

Comment: @fregomene What do you mean by "clean Html text"? What does the TextView show and what do you want instead? Please [edit] your question to clarify this.

Comment: Seems you didn't properly understood the question. I need to remove HTML tags, like <div>, <br> etc and then set a clean String as a TextView. That's why i can't reduce my code as you suggested.

Comment: @fregomene yes, I misunderstood. See my edited answer.

Comment: Nope, this will not work as this method returns Spanned object, that's why I need to call toString()

Comment: @fregomene did you try it?

Comment: @ Code-Apprentice yep

Comment: @fregomene and what happened?