# How do applications store and display attributed text (similar to HTML)

Tags: android, ios, html

I was wondering how do applications store and display attributed text. By attributed text I mean text that can have photos, colors, style(bold italic etc) and so on.

is there a universal way through which one can store attributed text and display it everywhere (ios/android/web/desktop etc) ?

the only way I found after a lot of research was to store your text in HTML format and then using some kind of webview to render the html back. But is there another way to do this ?

an example of such app: the notes app on mac os

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why doesn't the WebView approach not work for you?

Comment: it works fine if you just want to display data but it gets more complicated when you want to implement it in text fields in IOS and Android or basically anything other than web

Comment: If you need to display html text on TextView, check this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview#answer-2116191

Comment: sorry, I used textview as a broad term here. what I meant is any textfield or anything where you can input text into

Comment: You can't just have styled text in ANY kind of text input. What are you trying to achieve exactly?
You could use html or rtf, but ofc it only works if the app you're using is actually programmed to parse it.

Comment: that is exactly my point, how do i edit html text inside an application ? in the system i am building all html text will be edited in a website using an html editor (tinyMCE) and displayed on mobile devices using webviews but I was just thinking it would be convenient if i can have html editing capabilities in the app as well

Comment: Oh, now we're getting somewhere. You should give this library a try for that:
https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android

Comment: Thanks a lot! that is exactly what I needed and i also found an IOS one here https://github.com/cjwirth/RichEditorView. Thanks again !

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help ;)