# TextView: How to italicise one word in a sentence

Tags: android, textview, italics

Hey guys =) android newbie here.
I'm trying to write a sentence in TextView, and I only want one word in the sentence to be in italics.
for e.g. 
android:text="my name isn't Amber?" ==> I want only the word "isn't" to be italicised. 
Any help would be appreciated.
TIA!

Comment: you can use html format see in link for html format https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve that is using a [Spannable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html), A `StyleSpan` with `Typeface.ITALIC` on `isn't`, in your case, and then setting the resulting `CharSequence` to the `TextView`. Another way is to use an `Html` string, enclosing `isn't` between `<i></i>`, and formatting it with `Html.fromHtml`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plain old html tags. This should do the trick:

```
String txt = "My name <i>isn't</i> Amber"; 
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(txt,TO_HTML_PARAGRAPH_LINES_CONSECUTIVE));
```