# How to use display html tags along with inline css in android. The content is passed from the server to android via an API

Tags: android, html, css, inline

**I have gone through this link for reference**
https://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html

Answer (score 0):

The information is right there on your link. To use it as a spannable you have to call the fromHtml() method on your textview. After initializing the component. Please refer to this question:

[How to display HTML in TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview)

All your answers are there, sorry for not formatting the answer correctly I'm on mobile at the moment

Comment: The issue is regarding inline css.

Comment: In that case you should use a `WebView` which will allow you to format with HTML and CSS. Please take a look at this link: http://www.hidroh.com/2016/02/27/richtext-textview-versus-webview/  Be warned, `WebView` is pretty resource heavy. For simple CSS use a third party library which will allow you to format your `TextView`. For example: https://github.com/Pixplicity/HtmlCompat Note that not all CSS tags are supported. A list of supported tags lies in the documentation of the library.

Comment: `htmlData = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\" />" + htmlData;
// lets assume we have /assets/style.css file
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);` You can also load preconfigured CSS files with a URL like the code above.