# Android best way to display html text

Tags: android, webview, textview

I have string with `html tags`, `links`, `image links` so what is the best way to display this string? I know that people using `Webview` for that but maybe there is a way to do it in textview without putting too much work? Because with `WebView` comes different problems for example if you want to change text color you need to add extra style to that string. I'm interested in ways to make links clickable and displaying Images in the same textview.

Comment: What is the complete list of tags that you will be using in the HTML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display HTML in TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview)

Comment: Its not duplicate you see I know how to display html in textview but how about links and making them clickable using textview and as well displaying images from link inside this textview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**`Try using this`**:-

```
Html.fromHtml("your html code");
```

**`Example`**:-

```
txtvw.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p align=right> <b> "
        + "Hi!" + " <br/> <font size=6>"
        + " How are you "+"</font> <br/>"
        + "I am fine" + "  </b> </p>"));
```

**`Output`**:-

**Hi

  How are you

  I am fine**

`**Full Code With Image And Hyperlink**`:-

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 String htmlString = "<img src='ic_launcher'><i>Welcome to<i> <b><a href='https://stackoverflow.com/'>Stack Overflow</a></b>";

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  TextView htmlTextView = new TextView(this);
  setContentView(htmlTextView);

  htmlTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString, new Html.ImageGetter(){

   @Override
   public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
    Drawable drawable;
    int dourceId = 
      getApplicationContext()
      .getResources()
      .getIdentifier(source, "drawable", getPackageName());

    drawable = 
      getApplicationContext()
      .getResources()
      .getDrawable(dourceId);

    drawable.setBounds(
      0, 
      0, 
      drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
      drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

    return drawable;
   }

  }, null));

  htmlTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

 }

}
```

**`To support all API use this function`**:-

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static Spanned fromHtml(String html) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
    }
    else {
        return Html.fromHtml(html);
    }
}
```

Comment: how about making links clickable or displaying images?

Comment: Nice! one more thing from I guess 27 api fromHtml is deprecated would this approach work with 27 and higher api's?

Answer (score 0):

The way it only worked for me was:

```
class HelpActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.help_activity)
        val txtView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.help_textView)
        val str = resources.getString(R.string.help_textview)
        txtView.text = Html.fromHtml(str, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
    }
}
```

and the string resource uses a CDATA wrapper:

> ]]>

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what previously written, I find that using Html.fromHtml and HtmlCompat do not rendered ordered list (i.e. with numeric header)

```
<ol><li>...</li></ol>
```

I find this library that render that tag and it works for me: [HtmlTextView](https://github.com/SufficientlySecure/html-textview)