# Show an image and text from a string and display it in a textview

Tags: android

I have a string contains HTML tags for example

```
String html = "<h2><i>Title</i></h2><img src=/"https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_forest.jpg."><p>Description here</p>";
```

I need to display this image and the text in a textbox. Different strings have different images. This code showing only a square instead of the picture.

Comment: You can't display Image in textview you need to set HTML content in webview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display HTML in TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview)

Comment: You can't display image in a textview, you must use a WebView or create a ImageView instead.

Answer (score 1):

The XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="8">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_atXML"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView_atXML"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0"
        android:layout_weight="6"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textView;
    WebView webView;
    String html;
    String urlImage;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView=findViewById(R.id.textView_atXML);
        webView=findViewById(R.id.webView_atXML);
        html = "<h2><i>Title</i></h2><img src='https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_forest.jpg'><p>Description here</p>";
        urlImage="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_forest.jpg";
        textView.setText(html);
        webView.loadUrl(urlImage);

    }
}
```

And in the manifest you must to ask permission to use internet connection:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`