# hightlighting a couple of words in textview

Tags: android

I have a `TextView` with text and a `Button` that when i press highlight the word **hello** if it finds it in the text .
working on a project in the android studio and I'm totally novice so if u can help point me in the right direction thx in advanced.
for now, my app only highlight the word - hello

example :
String textToHighlight = "hello";

How can I make it highlight the list of words from a file or database or just a simple line of code 
example :
in the `TextView` there words " hello people i love u all "
and I want to highlight hello and love

Comment: Android allows to display HTML in TextView, so maybe you can construct dynamic HTML and set it on your TextView. This is one link for your reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display HTML in TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a `SpannableString` for this, which allows individual parts of a string to be rendered differently in a TextView.

Like so:

```
SpannableString str = new SpannableString("Highlighted. Not highlighted.");
str.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), 0, 11, 0);
textView.setText(str);
```

Comment: Q : Using span is by numbers like from 0 to 5 to highlight a word

Comment: yeah basically you put the color first then the start and end index which need to be hilighted

Comment: yeah although you would have to do bit of calculation before using it as you need to find out which are the index that needed to be hilighted

Comment: For now it's recognize the word hello by the word hello  , there isn't other methods beside span

Comment: yeah there is as you know textview can show the html tagged text so you could try and use that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview

Answer (score 0):

you can work with Span's 
Span in android is the way to giving color-font-background-etc to the pic's of the text inside the textview family here is great article about Spans

https://blog.stylingandroid.com/introduction-to-spans/

Comment: I know it took long time for me but I am using span like u said , thx for that .

Comment: Another Q , I have like 100 words to find in the textview What is faster to work with SQL or 100 lines of code for each word ?

Comment: @yan in my opinion using sql database just for handling this operation is bad you can use Regex to search through your text

Comment: now i am using  ssBuilder.setSpan(
                new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),
                text.indexOf("hello"),
                text.indexOf("hello") + String.valueOf("hello").length(),
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        ); and i have like 100 diffrenet  words to find , how Regex can help