# Paragraph and Bullets in Android

Tags: java, android, paragraph, bulletedlist

I'm working on a book app which is connected to a web admin.

I have added information about an author using paragraph and bullets in the web admin and it displays well but on the app, the paragraphs and bullets do not display and the text is all together.

Below is the Activity

```
public String getAuthorDescription() {
    return authorDescription;
}

public ArtistHeaderObject setAuthorDescription(String authorDescription) {
    this.authorDescription = authorDescription;
    return this;
}
```

Below is the Layout

```
<com.remmy.wisdomnuggets.TextviewUtil.UbuntuMediumTextview
        android:id="@+id/txt_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Peter Deuvergny"
        android:textDirection="locale"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorTagline"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Please, find attached a screenshot

[image]

Comment: By paragraphs and bullets, do you mean `<p>` and `<ul><li>`?

Comment: Good day. Yes, it displays well in the Web Admin but does not display well in the App. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display HTML in TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview)