# i have a data full html text and want to show in android

Tags: android

[{"FoodCoockingMethodID":282,"foodID":136,"foodName":"Chicken Soup","methodTypeID":4,"methodName":"Boiling\r\n","dishTypeID":3,"foodDishType":"Soup","coockingMethod":"<table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"815\" style=\"width: 611pt;\">\n <col width=\"815\" style=\"mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:29805;width:611pt\">\n <\/colgroup><tr height=\"177\" style=\"height:132.75pt\">\n  <td height=\"177\" class=\"xl66\" width=\"815\" style=\"height:132.75pt;width:611pt\">If\n  juice is refrigerated then stir first and then pour into the serving glass.<\/td>\n <\/tr>\n <tr height=\"31\" style=\"height:23.25pt\">\n  <td height=\"31\" class=\"xl71\" align=\"left\" width=\"815\" style=\"height:23.25pt;\n  width:611pt\">Ingredients<\/td>\n <\/tr>\n <tr height=\"25\" style=\"height:18.75pt\">\n  <td height=\"25\" class=\"xl69\" style=\"height:18.75pt\">1 (3 pound) whole chicken<\/td>\n <\/tr>\n <tr height=\"25\" style=\"height:18.75pt\">\n  <td height=\"25\" style=\"height:18.75pt\" align=\"left\" valign=\"top\"><!--[if gte vml 1]><v:shapetype\n   id=\"_x0000_t201\" coordsize=\"21600,21600\" o:spt=\"201\" path=\"m,l,21600r21600,l21600,xe\">\n   <v:stroke joinstyle=\"miter\"\/>\n   <v:path shadowok=\"f\" o:extrusionok=\"f\" strokeok=\"f\" fillok=\"f\"\n    o:connecttype=\"rect\"\/>\n   <o:lock v:ext=\"edit\" shapetype=\"t\"\/>\n  <\/v:shapetype><v:shape id=\"_x0000_s13280\" type=\"#_x0000_t201\" style='position:absolute;\n   direction:LTR;text-align:left;margin-left:0;margin-top:0;width:20.25pt;\n   height:23.25pt;z-index:3410' strokecolor=\"windowText [64]\" o:insetmode=\"auto\">\n   <v:imagedata src=\"file:\/\/\/C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\msohtmlclip1\\01\\clip_image001.emz\"\n    o:title=\"\"\/>\n   <x:ClientData ObjectType=\"Pict\">\n    <x:SizeWithCells\/>\n    <x:CF>Pict<\/x:CF>\n    <x:AutoPict\/>\n   <\/x:ClientData>\n  <\/v:shape><v:shape id=\"_x0000_s13281\" type=\"#_x0000_t201\" style='position:absolute;\n   direction:LTR;text-align:left;margin-left:0;margin-top:18.75pt;width:20.25pt;\n   height:23.25pt;z-index:3411' strokecolor=\"windowText [64]\" o:insetmode=\"auto\">\n   <v:imagedata src=\"file:\/\/\/C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\msohtmlclip1\\01\\clip_image001.emz\"\n    o:title=\"\"\/>\n   <x:ClientData ObjectType=\"Pict\">\n    <x:SizeWithCells\/>\n    <x:CF>Pict<\/x:CF>\n    <x:AutoPict\/>\n   <\/x:ClientData>\n  <\/v:shape><v:shape id=\"_x0000_s13282\" type=\"#_x0000_t201\" style='position:absolute;\n   direction:LTR;text-align:left;margin-left:0;margin-top:37.5pt;width:20.25pt;\n   height:23.25pt;z-index:3412' strokecolor=\"windowText [64]\" o:insetmode=\"auto\">\n   <v:imagedata src=\"file:\/\/\/C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\msohtmlclip1\\01\\clip_image001.emz\"\n    o:title=\"\"\/>\n   <x:ClientData ObjectType=\"Pict\">\n    <x:SizeWithCells\/>\n    <x:CF>Pict<\/x:CF>\n    <x:AutoPict\/>\n   <\/x:ClientData>\n  <\/v:shape><v:shape id=\"_x0000_s13283\" type=\"#_x0000_t201\" style='position:absolute;\n   direction:LTR;text-align:left;margin-left:0;margin-top:56.25pt;width:20.25pt;\n   height:23.25pt;z-index:3413' strokecolor=\"windowText [64]\" o:insetmode=\"auto\">\n   <v:imagedata src=\"file:\/\/\/C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\msohtmlclip1\\01\\clip_image001.emz\"\n    o:title=\"\"\/>\n   <x:ClientData ObjectType=\"Pict\">\n    <x:SizeWithCells\/>\n    <x:CF>Pict<\/x:CF>\n    <x:AutoPict\/>\n   <\/x:ClientData>\n  <\/v:shape><v:shape id=\"_x0000_s13284\" type=\"#_x0000_t201\" style='position:absolute;\n   direction:LTR;text-align:left;margin-left:0;margin-top:75pt;width:20.25pt;\n   height:23.25pt;z-index:3414' strokecolor=\"windowText [64]\" o:insetmode=\"auto\">\n   <v:imagedata src=\"file:\/\/\/C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\msohtmlclip1\\01\\clip_image001.emz\"\n    o:title=\"\"\/>\n   <x:ClientData ObjectType=\"Pict\">\n    <x:SizeWithCells\/>\n    <x:CF>Pict<\/x:CF>\n    <x:AutoPict\/>\n   <\/x:ClientData>\n  <\/v:shape><v:shape id=\"_x0000_s13285\" type=\"#_x0000_t201\" style='position:absolute;\n   direction:LTR;text-align:left;margin-left:0;margin-top:93.75pt;width:20.25pt;\n   height:23.25pt;z-index:3415' strokecolor=\"windowText [64]\" o:insetmode=\"auto\">\n   <v:imagedata src=\"file:\/\/\/C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\msohtmlclip1\\01\\clip_image001.emz\"\n    o:title=\"\"\/>\n   <x:ClientData ObjectType=\"Pict\">\n    <x:SizeWithCells\/>\n    <x:CF>Pict<\/x:CF>\n    <x:AutoPict\/>\n

Comment: You can show html text in `TextView` or use `WebView` if you want

Comment: You can show html text in TextView . check this out : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2116191/15306400

Answer (score -1):

You can show this in TextView

Java

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
} else { 
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));
}
```

Or Kotlin

```
textView.text = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
} else {
    Html.fromHtml(html)
}
```

There is a possibility that this method is unable to completely parse all the table tags. In that case, you'll be left with only one option i.e using `WebView`

Example:

```
webView.loadData(yourData, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Better to link the answer rather than copy pasting... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview/2116191#2116191

Comment: C'mon !! I had to add the webview solution as well.