# Resource String Color not working programmatically in Android

Tags: android, string, textview

**string.xml**
Here is my string

```
<string name="bullet_text"><font color="#38d98a">●</font>\t\tCucumber Detox Water (1 glass)\n<font color="#38d98a">●</font>\t\tSkimmed Milk (1 glass)\n<font color="#38d98a">●</font>\t\tPeas Poha (1.5 katori)</string>
```

When this string is used in xml it works perfectly but when using this string programmatically then it does not works

**xml code**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/bullet_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
```

**Working Perfectly**

[image]

**Kotlin Code**

```
 val textView:TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView)
 textView.text = getString(R.string.bullet_text)
```

**Not Working Perfectly**

[image]

Comment: try [Like This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2116191/4168607).

Comment: it works but \n in string not working

Comment: now it works I replace \n to <br/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now It Works Answer is here thanks @ADM and @Rasheed for commenting help

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="bullet_text"><![CDATA[<font color="#38d98a">●</font>\t\tCucumber Detox Water (1 glass)<br/><font color="#38d98a">●</font>\t\tSkimmed Milk (1 glass)<br/><font color="#38d98a">●</font>\t\tPeas Poha (1.5 katori)]]></string>
```

**Kotlin code**

```
val textView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView)
        textView.text = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.hello_worldRed), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
        } else {
            Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.hello_worldRed))
        }
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Please use HtmlCompat instead of Html to not do this check by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

you can use SpannableString to set bullet before your string :

```
val string = SpannableString("Text with\nBullet point")
        string.setSpan(
            BulletSpan(40, Color.GREEN, 20),
            10,
            22,
            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        )
        binding.textView.text = string
```

**here is the result**

[image]

Also see this->[BulletSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/BulletSpan)

**UPDATE**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28) {

    val string = SpannableString("Text with\nBullet point")
    string.setSpan(
        BulletSpan(40, Color.GREEN, 20),
        10,
        22,
        Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    )
    binding.textView.text = string
}else {
        // your own code
    }
```

Comment: it does not work bellow API Level 28

Comment: @Yaqoob Bhatti now its ok

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use custom style instead of string
<style name="CustomFontStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:capitalize">characters</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12pt</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">your font</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#38d98a</item>/>
</style>
```

Comment: But in my scenario i need string

Comment: use <br/> if you want to break the string in two parts like

Comment: <string name="register">
    Sign up <br/>
    Enjoy a new shopping life stack.com!!
</string>