# Line break for Mobile application

Tags: android, mysql

I have an address column on MySql Database like below.

[image]

This table data is fetching by Mobile Application. I would like to apply line break on address column data for Mobile application. How can I store data in Address column so that it will look like below in Mobile Application ?

2nd floor,
Stock Exchange Building,
9/F Motijheel C/A
Dhaka-1000

Comment: You first need to know how could they render your code? Does the label support HTML markups (or other specific markups?)

Comment: Save your Address like, Building Number, Street Name/Number, Area, State, Country, Pincode. And create a schema out of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the data for address in HTML content string-

you can use `<br>` tag for this and tell to Android developer to load address string as HTML content. It will solve the problem.

Reference for Android developer- [How to display HTML in TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview)

**OR**

we can use \n for break line in Android,so you can store address in below format, It may work.

```
"2nd floor, \n Stock Exchange Building, \n 9/F Motijheel C/A \n Dhaka-1000"
```

Comment: Thanks @Aditya Nandardhane. What should I do if I can't talk to Android Developer ? Is there any MySql way ? Thanks.

Comment: @abuabu  In android we can use \n for next line so you can try this, It may work.

 e.g. "2nd floor, \n
Stock Exchange Building, \n
9/F Motijheel C/A \n
Dhaka-1000"