# html style not applied to textView in Android

Tags: android, html

I get the Html String from the server.
I applied this serverString to `TextView` using `HtmlCompat`.
The inside of the body tag works correctly, but the inside of the style tag does not work, and the  code is exposed to TextView as it is.

```html
val serverString = """
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: 'Noto Sans KR', sans-serif;
                font-size: 14pt;
                color: #333;
            }
            p {
                margin-bottom: 16px;
            }
            .underline {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
            .red {
                color: #FF0000;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is a sample text with <b>bold</b>, <i>italic</i>, and <span class="underline">underline</span> text.</p>
        <p>This is another paragraph with <span class="red">red</span> text.</p>
        <p>This is a long paragraph with line breaks:<br/>
            First line<br/>
            Second line<br/>
            Third line
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

```kotlin
binding.textView.text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(serverString, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```

Below is the result image.

[image]

How can I get the  code to be applied correctly applied?

Comment: First thing remove 2 `"` from start and end there should be only one `"..."` and then refer this.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2116191/12833551

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong with this but what I understood, the problem here is that HtmlCompat doesn't support  tag. so it can't compile css styling.

You can try to go with two approach here -

1. Either change your html and apply styling with html tags inside body. This way your styling will work.
2. Or you can try to create a custom tag handler for  tag that can compile styling and then apply the same styling to respective tag.

As of now, I don't have any concrete solution for creating Tag handler so I'll suggest you to go with changing your html layout..