# Render html in TextView - Android

Tags: android

I need to render bellow html in `textView` but don't show any thing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://test.com/theme/mou_classic/css/vazir.css">
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: Vazir;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: bold;
        src: url('https://test.com/theme/mou_classic/fonts/Vazir/ttf/Vazir-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
    }

    body {
        font-family: Vazir, Tahoma;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: 2em;
    }

    h5 {
        color: maroon;
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    h6 {
        color: gray;
        font-size: 11px;
    }
</style>
<div style="border: solid 1px silver;width:80%;padding: 25px;display: table;margin: auto;direction: rtl">
    <h1 style="text-align: center">
RRTEDFGDF
    </h1>

    <div style="display: table;margin: auto">
        <img src="https://test.com/images/news/137.jpg" style="border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto">
    </div>

    <h6>
WERWER
    </h6>

    <div>
QWEWERRR
        <h5>WW </h5>

AAAA
    </div>

    <table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;margin: auto;width: 50%">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>13</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

I render like bellow:

```
binding.txtHtml.text = Html.fromHtml(resources.getString(R.string.html))
```

Comment: You are loading custom styling. I think you need to use `WebView` instead ..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display HTML in TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview)

Comment: @HalilOzel that question says to do exactly this, so... no.  The actual issue is that `Html.fromHtml` does not support all this stuff, especially the CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot render `Html` in `TextView` as TextViews are for displaying text and it cannot parse HTML tags.

There are alternate implementations of TextViews that can deal with HTML Tags

##### html-textview

Repo Link: https://github.com/sakacyber/html-textview

examples:

add dependency

```
implementation "com.github.sakacyber:html-textview:1.0.15"
```

xml

```
<com.saka.android.htmltextview.HtmlTextView
    android:id="@+id/htmlTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp" />
```

applying

```
binding.htmlTextView.setText(html, lifecycleScope)
```

Comment: What is the advantage of this over a `WebView`?  It doesn't seem to support CSS, either (see [here](https://github.com/sakacyber/html-textview/issues/2#issuecomment-1326670431) or [the code that only reads the HTML](https://github.com/sakacyber/html-textview/blob/master/html-textview/src/main/java/com/saka/android/htmltextview/utility/EManager.kt), so it won't even handle the HTML from the question.